# Chrome Extension to perform Regex substitution redirect

Tags: google-chrome-extension

```
[{
  "id" : 1,
  "priority": 1,
  "action" : { "type" : "redirect", "redirect": {"regexSubstitution": "\\0#test"} },
  "condition" : {
    "regexFilter" : "^https://subdomain.domain.com(.*)",
    "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
  }
}]
```

I am trying to write a short extension to redirect a specific format of web address to a slightly different address; this is for something internal to our organisation, and will make staff members' lives easier.
I have slightly modified my code (above) to remove anything too specific.
The rule returns no errors, but it does nothing. It does not seem to matter how I modify either the filter or the substitution either, I can't get it to do anything - all webpages load normally.
I assume I am overlooking something dumb, but I am not experienced in Chrome Extension development by any means; any help would be appreciated.

With the given code, I would have expected e.g.
'https://subdomain.domain.com/helloworld' to redirect to 'https://subdomain.domain.com/helloworld#test'.

I have struggled to find anything helpful because most examples are too old, and are for lower Manifest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked that your extension has host permissions under the `host_permissions` manifest key for the host you're trying to redirect on (`https://subdomain.domain.com` in your example)? Certain DNR rules require host permissions and without these, the extension will load but the rule will be ignored.

As a note, your rule as written will perform a redirect loop because it redirects to a page that would also match the rule. You'll likely want to find a way to avoid that.

Comment: The loop was due to bad "mangling" when I tried to take out the organisation specific text!
The problem was indeed the host_permission was not quite right, and the rule was being ignored, but not not wrong in such a way that threw an error.
Thank you!